# Is it possible to get positive radius of convergence for composition of two formal power series, if none of them has positive RoC.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, formal-power-series

I get counter example/proof for all other possibilities. But this one I couldn't do.

Comment: If your power series are $f = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_k z^k$ and $g = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty b_k z^k$ and you want to consider $f ∘ g$, do you assume that $b_0 = 0$? Otherwise I don't think that the composition is defined, because $f$ has zero radius of convergence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take any power series $F=a_1 X+a_2 X^2+\ldots$ with $a_1\not=0$ with radius of convergence $0$ and $G:=F^{-1}$. Then $G$ also has radius of convergence $0$ because otherwise also $F=G^{-1}$ would have a positive radius of convergence. Finally $F\circ G=X$ has $\infty$ as its radius of convergence.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but $F$ seems not to be invertible. Maybe you wanted to write $a_0+a_1X+\dots$ with $a_0\neq 0$?

Comment: Invertibility is meant with respect to composition rather than to multiplication.

Comment: Of course, you are right. Is it easy to see that the condition $a_1\neq 0$ makes $F$ invertible with respect to composition?

Comment: I figured it out. Really nice answer (+1).

Comment: See
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series for information on formal power series. In particular there is a section on composition and compositional inverse